# How to tell excel the delimiter/separator of a CSV

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

I am looking for a solution to tell Excel what is the separator for a CSV file. The idea is to have this configuration inside the file, for example:

**csv file example:**

```
document_separator: '|'

col_header_1 | col_header_2
first value | second value
... | ...
```

I already did some searching but I didn't find anything.
Thank you in advance.

**Btw this file is supposed being created using Javascript.**

Comment: If you are working with Excel, use the txt assistant or just create a better than just open with excel. If you are not working with Excel, don´t tag as Excel question,

Comment: I'm not working with excel for creating the file, but I need to tell excel how to read it. The file is to be used by different users in different platforms.